# MongoDB: Populate or Query for two collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following Schemas:

```
let ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String
  },
  employees: {
    user: String, // ==> ObjectId of User from UserSchema
    role: String,
    workload: Number,
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  }
});

let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  projects: {
    type: Array // ==> ObjectId of Project from ProjectSchema
  }
});
```

What I want to achieve is to get the user by `_id` or `email` and to get also all data from his projects like:

```
{
    "user": {
        "_id": "asdf1234",
        "email": "your@email.com",
        "name": "Max"
        "projects": {
            "title": "Project 1",
            "description": "Just a text",
            "employees": {
                "user": "asdf1234",
                "role": "developer",
                "workload": 40
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I also want to get a specific project by Id and the employee.user field should be populated with the correct user data.

Can I do this with Mongoose `populate`?
My approach would be to first do a `User.findOne()` and then check the project.id and to a `Project.findOne()`.

Comment: Both are old ways. Try with something new https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins

Comment: Could you provide an example based on my Schemas?

Comment: pls show sample collection so that I can produce some output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about in your UserSchema you reference an array of projects, that way when you query for the user you are querying for all the projects tied to the user.

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");
let Projects = require("./projects");
let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  projects: {
    type: [Projects.schema]
  }
});
```

Then every time you query for the user it comes with the projects associated to the user.